# Long form of "typo"

Tags: abbreviations

The definition of *typo*, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/typo):

> a small mistake in a text made when it was typed or printed

Can anyone tell me the long form of *typo*?

Comment: You can check the origin of a word in dictionary that has etymology. [typo](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=typo) such as etymonline.com.  But also [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/typo) and several others.

Comment: "typo" is clearly the short form of "tyop"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Typo is short for "typographical error".

From [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/typo):

> noun, plural ty·pos.Informal.
> typographical error.

Comment: We usually use the term to mean errors of the _typing_ (wrong letters, or wrong order), rather than of the _typography_ (wrong font or positioning).

Comment: @TobySpeight But when you realize that this term originated ~200 years ago it makes sense that all the accidental errors to do with typesetting would have the same name, from putting the right letter in the wrong font to putting the wrong letter in the right font. Of course we've expanded it (a lot) now, but this is far from the first English word/phrase to have strayed from it's original meaning.

Answer (score -2):

### typing error

I advocate *typing error* for present-day usage.

This better than *typographical error* reflects what is used in other languages, for example German *Tippfehler*, French *erreur de frappe* (or *faute de frappe*), Danish *tastefejl* (literally *keying error*).

It’s also the meaning that I have always understood from *typo*: an error made in typing.

Obviously, if what you intended was an error in the typography without regard to how that error has come about, then you should say that: *typographical error*.

### The origin of *typo*

Edit: PC Luddite commented:

> This may be a more accurate description of what a typo is, but it
> doesn't explain its origin.

I get your point. Maybe I interpreted the question of *the long form of “typo”* a bit differently from you. I agree that origin is relevant, though. So let’s take it, here from Online Etymology Dictionary (link at the bottom):

> 1816, "compositor," short for typographer; 1892 as short for
> typographical error

My interpretation was more, when people use *typo* in 2022, what would be the long form? So I answered what I think people mean by it today, not what they meant more than 100 years ago.

Link: [*typo* in Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/typo)